# How to draw an arrow in SVG?

Tags: html, svg

I need to make it flexible. It can be some type of lines and arrows on the end of lines.

So, I decided to create two SVG objects: lines and an arrowhead.

How to draw an arrowhead on the end or beginning of the line?

My line is:

```html
<svg width="500" height="100">
  <line x1="0" y1="80" x2="100" y2="20" stroke="black" />
</svg>
```

Comment: use a [marker](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Element/marker)

Comment: Is it possible to chnage direction of arrawhead? Could you share an sample?

Comment: line does not have marker-start

Comment: visit the link for an example and line **does** have marker-start.

Comment: draw it with an svg editor inkscape for example and edit the svg to take a look

Comment: Check out https://jsfiddle.net/umxrw3sd/  arrow looks awful, how to move it to the end ?

Comment: in your fiddle you need to change the `refX` to a smaller value: try 5 or 6. This will make the marker to go outside the svg canvas, so you'll need to also change the value of the viewBox to `viewBox="0 0 110 100"` to make the svg wider

Comment: Thank you. could you tell me how to draw arrow not filled it by color, just borders?

Comment: Make the fill none, or white, and give it a stroke.  Eg. `<path d="M 0 0 L 10 5 L 0 10 z" fill="white" stroke="black" stroke-width="1"/>`  But remember you may need to adjust the viewBox to allow for the extra size of the stroke.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can use `defs` and `path` — http://jsfiddle.net/jxtfeqag/

```html
<svg>
  <defs>
    <marker 
      id='head' 
      orient="auto" 
      markerWidth='3' 
      markerHeight='4' 
      refX='0.1' 
      refY='2'
    >
      <path d='M0,0 V4 L2,2 Z' fill="black" />
    </marker>
  </defs>

  <path
    id='arrow-line'
    marker-end='url(#head)'
    stroke-width='4'
    fill='none' stroke='black'  
    d='M0,0, 80 100,120'
  />
        
</svg>
```